# Do any Christian groups forbid lending at interest?

Tags: money

Is charging or paying interest disallowed by any groups in Christianity, and if so which ones?

So for example I sell someone a laptop and they don't have the full money right now and lets say the laptop cost £500 so then I tell them they can pay over two years but I will expect a total payment of £700 instead. The extra £200 will be interest.

Comment: Closely related [Lending with Interest in Christianity](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/44423)

Comment: [Why do some Christians think it's not a sin to charge interest?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/1207)  Even closer related