# Did Jesus forbid debt collection?

Tags: exegesis, gospel-of-luke, money

In both Luke 6:34,

> And **if you lend to those from whom you expect to receive, what credit is that to you**? Even sinners lend to sinners to be repaid in full.

and Luke 6:35,

> But love your enemies, do what is good, and **lend, expecting nothing in return**. Then your reward will be great, and you will be sons of the Most High. For He is gracious to the ungrateful and evil.

it appears as though Jesus is forbidding Christians from participating in any form of debt collection.  Is this understanding accurate?

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE. For a quick overview of what this site is about, please take the [Site Tour](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour). For your question to work well here, you'd need to specify the denomination or group of Christians whose answer you want--since there are too many different answers to this question depending upon who you ask. See: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) Meanwhile, I hope you'll stick around and browse some of the questions and answers here.

Comment: Related: [Why do some Christians think it's not a sin to charge interest?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/1207/21576)

Comment: For clarity by 'debt collection', do you mean forcing people to repay debts, or receiving repayment of loans?

Comment: By "debt collection" I mean forcing or urging people to pay, not merely receiving repayment.